# NMS wsdl integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUGrD.png)I used NMS wsdl to get nodes info.

When I called `NBC.getNodes(arg0);` I am getting this error.

Below is my code:

```
    NmsNodeClient NBC = new NmsNodeClient(binding, address); 
    filter arg0 = new filter();
    arg0.condition = new condition();
    arg0.constraint = new constraint();
    arg0.expression = new expression();
    NBC.getNodes(arg0);
```

**Error**:
Message: The top XML element 'arg0' from namespace '' references distinct types System.String and System.String[]. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types.

**Stack Trace**:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ReconcileAccessor(Accessor accessor, NameTable accessors)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ReconcileLocalAccessor(ElementAccessor accessor, String ns)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMemberMapping(XmlReflectionMember xmlReflectionMember, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)

Comment: yes, I used Add Service Reference.
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://00.00.00.00/NodeBeanService/NodeBean");

Comment: And what do you mean by NMS? Many products use those acronyms. WCF uses the WS-* interoperability standards that were adopted in the late 00s which means it may complain when used with earlier, non-compliant services. Or is this your own service?

Comment: I just want to know what does filler means, why we need write this.

arg0.condition = new condition();
arg0.condition.condition.name = "";
arg0.condition.condition.@operator = ???;

Comment: How can anyone answer that without knowing what you talk about?

Comment: if you share any reference where this type of filter used.

Comment: What filter? This has nothing to do with WCF. Those are classes generated by the WSDL file or web service you used. Right now, only you know what service you used. NMS is a common acronym

Comment: I have attached image for more understanding.